websockets: Invalid session ID. The session may have been already closed
we are try to connect biometric device using websockets , it works fine in asp.net. we use same class library in mvc not working getting we 'Invalid session ID. The session may have been already closed.
DeviceLoginManager Class:
    public static OnlineDevice[] GetOnlineDevices() //error
    {
        List<OnlineDevice> online = new List<OnlineDevice>();

        foreach(Guid guid in SessionRegistry.GetKeys())
        {
            if (SessionRegistry.GetSession(guid).loggedIn)
            {
                online.Add(new OnlineDevice { session = SessionRegistry.GetSession(guid) });
            }

            const int KeepAliveTimeout = 10 * 60 * 1000;
            SBWebSocketHandler aSession = SessionRegistry.GetSession(guid);
            if (aSession.keepAliveMsgSupported &&
                aSession.keepAliveRecvedTime < Environment.TickCount - KeepAliveTimeout)
            {
                aSession.Close();
            }
        }

        return online.ToArray();
    }

SessionRegistry Class
internal static object _monitor = new object(); internal static Dictionary<Guid, SBWebSocketHandler> _sessions = new Dictionary<Guid, SBWebSocketHandler>(); private static RandomNumberGenerator _random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create(); /// <summary> /// Retrieves an open session from its ID. /// </summary> /// <param name="guid">Session ID</param> /// <returns>A session object if matching ID was found; otherwise null</returns> public static SBWebSocketHandler GetSession(Guid guid) { lock (_monitor) { SBWebSocketHandler result; if (_sessions.TryGetValue(guid, out result)) return result; else { // return null; throw new WebDeviceException("Invalid session ID. The session may have been already closed."); } } } internal static Guid AddSession(SBWebSocketHandler handler) { lock (_monitor) { byte[] guidBytes = new byte[16]; Guid guid; do { _random.GetBytes(guidBytes); guid = new Guid(guidBytes); } while (_sessions.ContainsKey(guid)); _sessions.Add(guid, handler); return guid; } } public static Dictionary<Guid, SBWebSocketHandler>.KeyCollection GetKeys() { lock (_monitor) { return _sessions.Keys; } }


SBWebSocketHandler Class:
private IDeviceLoginManager _loginManager;
public Guid SessionId { get { return m_guid; } }
public override void OnOpen()
{
   _loginManager = (IDeviceLoginManager)
       Type.GetType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smackbio.websocketsdk.deviceLoginManager"])
       .GetConstructor(new Type[0])
       .Invoke(new object[0]);

   m_guid = SessionRegistry.AddSession(this);

   registerMsgRecved = false;
   loggedIn = false;
   keepAliveMsgSupported = false;

}





What do you mean by works fine in asp.net and mvc?  you could even use asp.net to create a console app. if your MVC project you mentioned was web (because Model View Controller it is just structure ) you need middleWare

biometric device connected successfully in asp.net

if your second  project you mentioned as MVC was any kind of Web project, and your project which you called asp.net was any type of  Windows app, you need to use middleWare for connect it

Add GenericHandler.ashx in your project
